# There is a common practice to reject "malicious" user-input to a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, url, validation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to know what is a common practice to prevent to store "malicious" values in the database.

For example, I have a database table column means to store URLs. A user, passing the validation (just a length check), can submit a URL like `http://<script>alert('hello!');</script>`. *I would like to do not permit to store links like the above...* **how can I make that?**

Comment: Input-validation is where this needs to be stopped; extend your validation to include more than length-checking. This is not related to databases. Remember you will also need to perform output-encoding when later using the stored values in your output. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper thing to do is use [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) to parse the supposed URL and then check each component:

```
validate :url_check

def url_check
    u = URI.parse(self.url)
    # check u.scheme, u.userinfo, etc. and  call errors.add(:url, '...')
    # if something is invalid.
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    errors.add(:url, 'You are being naughty.')
end
```

Comment: @Sergio: I hate parsing so I employ True Laziness and let someone else do it for me, it is super effective.

Answer (score 1):

While those links are in the database, they do no harm. Problems might occur when you try to render them. Rails does a good job in escaping most things that you output (I didn't dare to say "everything", 'cause I don't know for sure).

You can be extra sure and escape a string yourself:

```
CGI.escape your_link_url
```

Link: [CGI.escape](http://rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=M000523&name=escape)

Comment: I have problems when I render them: `URI::InvalidURIError`.

Comment: @user502052: when you render them escaped or as is?

Comment: Well, that's because it isn't a valid url :-) I guess, you're using `link_to` and it does some validation and escaping inside.

Comment: So, how could/should I proceed?

Comment: @user502052: it's not rendering - it's not doing any harm. Problem solved?

Comment: @user502052: if I were you, I would check those links against blacklist before insertion. (check that they don't contain `<script` and stuff like this) and let Rails handle the rest.

Comment: Maybe I should check unsafe URLs as stated in the RFC 1738 documentation (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)... but what is the regex?

Comment: @user502052: you have the rfc, try to figure out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to validate it's a valid url without the '<', '>' url. And HTML encode it where it applies.

Comment: What do you means with "And HTML encode it where it applies"?

Comment: If you are displaying the link to the user, you need to HTML encode it so that the script is not executed.

Comment: I would like to solve the underlying problem by avoiding to store "malicious" links.